# Simplest, cheapest way to detect if a motor is running?

Tags: arduino, motor

I'm trying to design a system that automatically logs the run time of several machines. What time they start, what time they finish, how many hours they ran during the day.

All the machines I want to track use motors, so at first glance, it seems like it could work to log the amperage used by the motors.  However, I don't actually need the reading for the number of amps, I just want to know the time the machine turned on and what time it turned off, I don't need to log all the numbers in between.

Does anyone know if an Arduino would be able to help me record the start/stop time only? Or have a better idea of how to track this? Thanks for your thoughts.

Comment: Are you willing to insert components into/tap into the circuit which controls the motors, or do you want the modifications to be non-intrusive?  What sort of circuit currently controls the motors? Are we talking about 5V dc motors the size of my thumb, 10kW induction motors, or something in between? You can edit your question to add this information.

Comment: There are many many many ways this could be done, current monitors, accelerometers, hall effect sensors, a microphone, rotary encoder. This question is too broad: http://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 4):

Since you don't care about motor current the simplest method would be to monitor an auxiliary contact of the motor control relay. This could be used to feed to the logger.

Arduino devices are not industrially hardened and will be susceptible to EMF, etc., won't panel mount easily, etc. You also have the problem of real-time clock / calendar and extracting the data from it. Better options would be:

- Industrial data logger.
- Mini-brick PLC. This is the most flexible as they have mains or 12 - 24 V inputs, network capability, SD card for data-logging, etc. Manufacturers include Siemens, Allen-Bradley, Crouzet, Mitsubishi, ...

[image]

*Figure 1. The Siemens LOGO! range has mini-HMI, keyboard, Ethernet, 8 inputs, 4 outputs, micro-SD, etc.*

[image]

*Figure 2. The Logosoft Comfort programming environment includes a graphical editor and simulator. Source: [PLC Compare](http://plccompare.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/02/WindLGC.png).*

Cost of the hardware is about €120, I think. Check if there is a free download of the software.

The advantages of this approach are:

- Industrial hardware - robust, finger-proof terminals, mains isolation, etc.
- Can be properly documented and supported by other engineers (who won't thank you for Arduino code).
- Integrated clock-calendar, network, HMI, logger and keypad.

---

If you insist on going the Arduino route then have a look at [Industruino](https://industruino.com/). They've industrialised the device to the same form-factor as the LOGO! above.

[image: Industruino exposed!]

*Figure 3. The Industruino packages an Arduino, display and I/O into a DIN-rail mountable package.*

Comment: You're correct. Major rewrite done.

Comment: That looks better :-)